# Invertible operators converging to a noninvertible operator in a finite dimensions: Eigenvalue converge to 0?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I feel like this should be an obvious property,  but I want to make sure of it before I use it as the key part of a larger proof:
If we have two finite dimensional vector spaces $E,F$ of the same dimension $m$, and a series of invertible operators $T_n:E\to F$ such that in operator norm, $T_n\to T$  and $T$ is not invertible,  then we must have at least one eigenvalue in the $T_n$ sequence approaching 0, correct?

Since in finite dimensions, we have singular iff a 0 eigenvalue,  and since all the operators are converging, and the eigenvalue computation is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, which is continuous....is this that obvious that I can just use, or is it deeper, or is it wrong?

Comment: I think that $E$ should be equal to $F$, otherwise speaking about eigenvalues is meaningless.

Comment: Well, it's finite dimensional, everything is equivalent to $\mathbb K ^m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $T_n, T$ are all endomorphisms of $E$, otherwise there is no meaning on speaking about eigenvalues. Let $n= \dim E$.

Denote by $m(S)= \min \{ |\lambda| : \lambda \mbox{ is an eigenvalue of } S\}$

And recall that $|\det S| = \prod_{\lambda \in \sigma(S)} |\lambda| \ge (m(S))^n$ for all endomorphisms $S$.

Since the determinant is continuous, you have
$$m(T_k)^n \le |\det T_k| \to 0$$
as $k \to \infty$. Hence $m(T_k) \to 0$.

This shows that the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Perfect,  that formalizes what I needed, thanks.   Now I can complete the rest of the proof :)